# ReactJS and targetting/wrapping elements like jQuery

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add 'sticky note' annotations (which i call TourPoints) to a React-based prototype I am creating. I created a TourPoint component which I have been manually 'wrapping' around elements of my interface as I go. The TourPoint displays the 'content' as a pink tag on the side of the element.

```
<TourPoint content="Sticky note content goes in this prop">
  <button id="elementToWrap">Button element to annotate</button>
</TourPoint>
```

[image]

However, this gets a little messy and bloats my code... With jQuery, I used to be able to write a script where I could keep something like TourPoints neatly in a separate javascript file, then simply target DOM ids or classes to append elements.

```
$("#elementToWrap").wrap( "<div class='tourpoint'>Sticky note content goes here</div>" );
// $.append() or $.insertBefore() were also useful functions for this kind of thing
```

I am wondering how I might do a similar thing in React, and thought refs { useRef } might come to the rescue - but have not used refs before and can't quite get my head around if this is the right approach, or whether I am barking up the wrong tree with this.

The idea would be able to reference a ref globally (?) so that i can simply append the TourPoint to the element from a separate js/jsx file (sorry, no code example, as I really don't know what this would look like...)

The ease of having my TourPoints managed from a central file for the application what i am trying to achieve. The application has multiple pages and use React-Router.

Any pointers on how to think about this problem in the 'React' way would be most welcome.

Comment: I think you can create a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) that have a "tourpoint" associated with him and then you can instance your "base" component

Comment: https://github.com/gilbarbara/react-joyride https://github.com/elrumordelaluz/reactour

Comment: Thanks for those resources both - I will have a dig through those examples and see if I can answer my question specifically about ref (if it has any relevance to the problem I am trying to solve).